# Average value of array subfield in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have around 1.06 M docs formatted like this :

```
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [
        [
            [
            -0.3994018,
            43.547069
            ],
            [
            -0.3994509,
            43.5469605
            ],
            [
            -0.3995154,
            43.5469097
            ],
            [
            -0.3995879,
            43.5468503
            ],
            [
            -0.3996707,
            43.5467618
            ],
            [
            -0.3997065,
            43.546666
            ]
        ]
    ]
},
"properties" : {
    "commune" : "64063",
    "section" : "A",
    "numero" : "105",
    "id" : "640630000A0105",
    "contenance" : 12280,
    "prefixe" : "000",
    "updated" : "2014-06-18",
    "created" : "2013-11-14"
},
"id" : "640630000A0105",
"type" : "Feature"
```

I'd like to request all the records where the average of **geometry.coordinates[0][X][0] (longitude)** is between two values and same thing for **geometry.coordinates[0][X][1] (latitude)**.

How can I ask this to elasticsearch ? range + avg ?

EDIT : here is the data mapping

```
{
  "parcelles" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "parcelle" : {
        "properties" : {
          "geometry" : {
            "properties" : {
              "coordinates" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "properties" : {
            "properties" : {
              "commune" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "contenance" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "created" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "numero" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "prefixe" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "section" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "updated" : {
                "type" : "date"
              }
            }
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to elastic so I don't have all the knowledge needed to spot some obvious mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the mapping details of the document? Or just the fields in question would also be fine!!

Comment: I added it. Hope, you can help me with that